# How to show git merges when I use git log?

Tags: git, git-merge

I don't know why git works like this but when I merge branch *A* into branch *B* and then use git log on branch *B*, all I see are the logs of all my commits from branch *A*. I thought I would see the list of commits and on top of those commits it would say *"Merged a into B"*.

I know I have seen in my log files *"Merge branch 'a' into branch 'b'"* when I worked on other projects so I don't know what I am doing wrong. What I am doing is completing a branch so I know it works. Checking out development and then merging the last branch I worked on into development. Any idea what I'm  doing wrong?

Comment: Was it a fast-forward merge?

Comment: Try `git log --first-parent`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git defaults to *fast-forward merge* option when there are no commits in branch *B*.
You have to use `--no-ff` switch to always create merge commit.

Comment: Thank you very much this is what i was looking for